# How to append divs into another div inside a variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I am trying to create a HTML code generator just for fun. My actual problem is: How can I append `div`s from a loop inside another `div` that does not exist and is saved in a variable?

I hope I have been clear, thank you.

My little JavaScript until now:

```
colCont = $("<div class=\"stab-cont\"><div class=\"stab-row\"></div></div>");

function repeat(n) {
  for (var i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
    //Here I need to insert the n DIVs generated by this loop
  }
}

repeat(3);

console.log(colCont);
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qo3vdwhv/

Comment: Why are you wrapping the string inside of a `$()`?

Comment: @jsve to get the element object? Am i wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be something like: `$('.stab-cont .stab-row')`? That should get you the `.stab-row` Node.

Comment: @jsve Your method will not work if the div does not exist...

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't realize that. Thanks for pointing that out. (I work mainly in Ext JS.)

Comment: Btw, `i < n + 1` can also be written here as `i <= n` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I am under thinking it here, but this should work.

My code:

```js
colCont = $("<div class=\"stab-cont\"></div>");

function repeat(n) {
  for (var i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
    $("<div class=\"stab-row\"></div>").appendTo(colCont); //build your div like you did with "colCont" and append the new div to colCont
  }
}

repeat(3);

colCont.appendTo($("body"))
```

```css
.stab-cont div {
  border: 1px solid #c00;
  margin: 10px;
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks, easy easy!

Comment: Personally when I am setting a variable to a HTML element I like to add s $ (e.g. $colCont) so I remember what it is.

Comment: A yeah, that's a good call. I often do the same thing. I'm glad I could help @CaioKawasaki!

Answer (score 1):

Here's something to consider; instead of making your `repeat()` function dependent on `colCont`, make it a jQuery function instead.

In this case I've created a function that will repeat the contents of a jQuery object N times (N >= 1).

```js
colCont = $("<div class=\"stab-cont\"></div>");

jQuery.fn.times = function(n) {
  var len = this.length;

  for (var i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    for (var k = 0; k < len; ++k) {
      this.push(this[0].cloneNode(true));
    }
  }
  return this;
};

colCont
  .append($('<div class="stab-row"></div>').times(3))
  .appendTo('body');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```